# yii active record via issue

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii2

Please help;

i have models:

```
class Service extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ServiceCategory::className(), ['id' => 'service_category_id']);
    }
}

class ServiceOffer extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function getService()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Service::className(), ['id' => 'service_id']);
    }

    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ServiceCategory::className(), ['id' => 'service_category_id'])->via('service');
    }

    public function getProperties()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ServiceProperty::className(), ['service_category_id' => 'id'])
                    ->via('category');
    }
}
```

When i do query:

```
$query = ServiceOffer::find()->with(['properties'])->all();
```

or:

```
$query = ServiceOffer::find()->joinWith(['properties'])->all();
```

i have error:

```
Getting unknown property: app\models\ServiceOffer::service_category_id
```

but if i do this for see query sql:

```
$query = ServiceOffer::find()->joinWith(['properties']);
echo $query->prepare(\Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder)->createCommand()->rawSql;
```

sql:

```
SELECT "service_offer".* FROM "service_offer" 
LEFT JOIN "service" ON "service_offer"."service_id" = "service"."id" 
LEFT JOIN "service_category" ON "service"."service_category_id" = "service_category"."id" 
LEFT JOIN "service_property" ON "service_category"."id" = "service_property"."service_category_id"
```

query without problem and execute

Why ActiveRecord find service_category_id property in ServiceOffer model?

Comment: Seems there is a bug in Yii. It's very similar to this: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5341